# Modal dialog is blocking secondary thread run

Tags: multithreading, qt, modal-dialog

My application spawns a secondary thread that performs long database tasks in background.
For to access the DB in the secondary thread I implemented [this good solution](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9602), and it works perfectly until I open a modal dialog: the execution of secondary thread in this case it is blocked until I close the Dialog.

How do I avoid this?
I want to leave the secondary thread free to perform database tasks for the antire life of my application, without interruption.

Comment: do you open your Dialog with QDialog::open or QDialog::exec ? because exec is blocking when open return imediately

Comment: I don't think a modal dialog actually blocks other threads. It probably blocks the main thread from processing event loop.

Comment: The dialog is called with QDialog::exec() because I have to manage the return code (the user could confirm or discard changes made inside the dialog). I can't use open because doesn't catch the return code.

Comment: Guys I solved it. I didn't create the worker object into the run() method of the secondary thread.. instead was built into the constructor of the thread, so the worker object was operating into the main UI thread.